# Degree or valency of a Cayley graph

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, cayley-graphs

Let $G$ be a group and $S \subseteq G$ be a generating set of $G$.

The Cayley digraph of $G$ with respect
to $S$, $X=\overrightarrow {\operatorname{Cay}}(G, S)$ is a graph whose vertices are the elements of $G$ and there is an edge from $g$ to $gs$
whenever $g \in G$ and $s \in S$.

The Cayley graph, $X = \operatorname{Cay}(G, S)$ is the undirected graph whose vertices
are the elements of $G$ and there is an edge from $g$ to $gs$ and from $g$ to $gs^{-1}$ whenever $g \in G$ and $s \in S$.

In a group, an element of order $2$ is known as an "involution". i.e. a non-identity element
whose square is the identity element.

So by thinking about the above definitions I have written the following about the degree of a Cayley graph, $X=\operatorname{Cay}(G,S)$ of a group $G$, with respect to a generator set $S$:

"$\deg(X)= 2\vert S \vert $, if $S$ has elements which are not involutions"

I would like to know whether above sentence is correct. Is it ok, to mention as "$S$ has elements which are not involutions"?

Comment: [You asked this in the group theory chatroom.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48238459#48238459) However, in order to avoid downvotes on this question or having it closed, please [edit] it to include more context, such as why the question is interesting to you, where it arose, and what you have done to solve it yourself :)

Comment: Ok, thanks @Shaun :) :)

Comment: Thank you @Shaun :) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer may depend on definitions of a [Cayley graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph#Definition) and vertex degree. Namely, if we consider the directed Cayley graph then in-degree of its each vertex equals to its out-degree and equals to $|S|$. If we consider the undirected Cayley graph then we assume that $S$ is symmetric and without the identity $\{e\}$ and then degree of its each vertex equals $|S|$.

Comment: Thanks @AlexRavsky I have added more details to the question as instructed. Do you think it's correct to mention about involutions ?

Comment: @BuddhiniAngelika According to the given definition of ${\operatorname{Cay}}(G, S)$ degree of any its vertex is $2|S|-|S_i|$, where $S_i=\{g\in S: g$ is an involution$\}$. In particular, if $S$ contains no involutions then degrere of each vertex of ${\operatorname{Cay}}(G, S)$ is $2|S|$.

Comment: Thank you very much @AlexRavsky